# Is this possible to handle which iOS notification is clicked on the notification centre?

Tags: ios, notifications

I would like to know, if the user click the notification in the notification centre, whether the application can detect which notification they are clicking and how I can handle it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In your app delegate, the notification details will be received in the method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`

The `userInfo` will have the payload that you sent with your push notification. It recommended that when you send a push notification that you include identifying information in the payload (such as an object id) to figure out which push notification was selected/received.

Comment: Yes, I can receive the notification information, but the problem is, let say the first notification is msg_a, the next one is msg_b, in the notification centre, it have both msg_a, and msg_b. I would like to know which one is the user clicked.

Comment: When you send out your push notification, include some data in the payload. For example, when you send out msg_a, include `"alert_type":"msg_a"`, and read that data in the `userInfo` that comes in.